# Notificação da View não funciona com mvvmhelper

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

Estou usando o mvvmhelper do James Montemagno, para desenvolver meu app e usando a mesma estrutura que ele ensina usar. ou seja com uma BaseViewModel e tal quando eu faço a navegação entre as paginas tudo funciona perfeitamente, carrego as propriedades no construtor da minha viewmodel e elas são exibidas no formulário.
mas quando executo alguma alteração nas mesmas propriedades que deveriam atualizar minha view, ela não atualiza, como se a alteração da propriedade não estivesse notificando  a view.

Alguem já passou por isso usando o mvvmhelper?

Comment: Coloque o código para facilitar a ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi sua pergunta, você está se referindo a uma ViewModel que não está atualizando na exibição da sua View, correto?
Para realizar isto sua ViewModel deve implementar INotifyPropertyChanged e no caso do MVVMHelper você deve utilizar SetProperty da seguinte forma, segue abaixo um exemplo de código:

```
public class PersonViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name{
       get{
           return _name;
       }
       set{
           SetProperty(ref _name, value);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Junior, você foi certeiro!
eu pensei que por usar o mvvmhelper eu poderia declarar minhas propriedades normalmente colocando no set isso

set { _visivelValidaEmail = value; }

mas na verdade tem que ser assim 
 SetProperty(ref _visivelValidaEmail, value);